# Vuetify Data Table pre-select based off array values

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I need to be able to pre-select items based on an array of id's that match up with my id's in my JSON data. I can pre-select if the data is in an json formatted object like my codepen, what I want to be able to do is pre-select based on just the id's themselves

https://codepen.io/jamiebrs/pen/NWWKvRP?&editable=true&editors=101

Where you see the

```
  selected: [{ "id": 3, "name": "Eclair", "calories": 262, "fat": 16, "carbs": 23, "protein": 6, "iron": "7%" } ],
```

I would like to be able to pass it as an array of items like so

```
  selected: [3,4,5]
```

and use those id's to pre-select. Any ideas?

Comment: You can write a method which maps selectedIds to the required selected array of objects

Comment: Is there not a way to just use the array of Id's as an attribute somewhere in the table that allows it to be selected?

Comment: It’s not supported by vuetify. You could also implement a wrapper component to achieve this mapping.

Comment: `selected: [3,4,5].map(id => ({ id }))` works if  `item-key="id"`

Comment: Thank you Ja9ad335h, that worked.

Comment: Thought @Jamie method works fine but one needs to be caraful because the 'selected' variable will then contain only the id's and not the full object which you application might expect. Because of this I store the full data and put it into 'selected' for preselection.